# How configure my beetel adsl2+ 440txi modem as a wireless access point for a pppoe connection

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, pppoe

I have a beetel router (adsl2+ 440txi) with wireless settings already configured and connected to laptop. This router is connected to another dsl router which is connected to the internet.

I tried configuring the beetel router by creating a new pppoe connection with the given username and password (going to 192.168.1.1 and creating a new connection). But it doesn't work; in the connection status for the router, the state is 'not connected' because the 'dsl line is disconnected'. The connection on the laptop says connected to wireless network but no internet access and the pppoe light on the router doesn't blink at all.

Wondering if i need to make any other configurations. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your Beetel 440txi router has a built-in DSL modem for its WAN port, and doesn't provide an Ethernet WAN port, is that correct?

If so, then you can't hook its (DSL) WAN port to your other DSL router's (Ethernet) LAN port, because DSL and Ethernet are two different technologies, even though their connectors may look similar in some countries (RJ11 for a telephone/DSL line, wider RJ45 for Ethernet cable).

Since you already have another DSL router plugged into your DSL-enabled telephone line, let that router be your PPPoE client, NAT gateway, and DHCP server for your home network. If you want to add the Beetel 440txi to the network to provide more Ethernet ports or additional Wi-Fi coverage, then turn off the 440txi's PPPoE, NAT, and DHCP services, and use and Ethernet cable to plug one of the 440txi's Ethernet LAN ports to one of the Ethernet LAN ports on the other DSL router.